# Updating Commerce Kickstart’s Contrib Modules

Tags: commerce

What is the recommended way to update outdated Drupal contrib modules? The Commerce Guys doing a great job to keep Commerce secure and updated. However there’s always a Contrib Module update around. For the most part this isn’t an issue. Most of the Contrib Module updates are maintenance fixes. However what about security fixes for Contrib Modules? Usually I don’t touch the /profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/crontrib folder and I am waiting until a new [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) release is published.

Does Commerce Kickstart uses special Contrib modules? Can I update [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools), [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand that Commerce Kickstart is a Distribution. So your goal is to learn how to update a Drupal distribution before their official release.

For the most part you would need to understand how [Drupal Make works](https://www.drupal.org/node/625094). Where is a great article ( [Maintaining your installed Drupal distro](https://www.acquia.com/blog/maintaining-your-installed-drupal-distro).) that would explain you how to maintain Drupal distributions.

If you successfully was able to update your Drupal distribution (commerce_kickstart) using Drupal Make. You should created a patch and provide that patch to the commerce_kickstart issue queue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am already using Drush, however I am new to Drush Make. Frankly I was looking for a more comfortable solution without creating own patches, that is why I've choosen Kickstarter.

Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.